# How to execute javascript functions in client-side in browsers with Node-JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to execute javascript code in **client-side** using node-JS, precisely I want to execute an **alert** when the user or the password is wrong to log to the website. Executing javascript in client code could even animate my website. How do I do that?

I tried to use npm alert-node, also npm js-alert, and npm popups, but those modules didn't work (no one mentioned). Really I think that those modules are not necessary if I just want to create an alert with a message "Error to log, try again".

If possible, can you give me a tutorial that explain **how to execute javascript in client-side in node js?** I use **express** with **EJS** and **bootstrap**. thanks.

Comment: One way to achieve this is create an html page with a javascript `<script>alert('hello')</script>` block within it. Then have that html page loaded into the user's browser when they hit an endpoint on your node server. Here is a link with a fairly easy example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files

Comment: Ok, so, imagine you were instead working with PHP. how would you get javascript to execute on the client browser when using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, per se.

You have two different programs running on two different computers. The fact they are written in the same programming language is beside the point.

The closest you can get is to write some client-side JavaScript that will show the alert when it receives a message over the network, and some server-side JavaScript which will send that message at the appropriate time.

Standard HTTP works is a stateless client-server protocol so using that you would have to poll (e.g. using the `fetch` API) the server to so it can respond with the message at the appropriate time.

A more efficient, but complex, approach would be to use WebSockets instead of HTTP so that the server and trigger the message.

Comment: I honestly think the problem lies much deeper than just understanding how to execute AJAX requests. I think the problem comes from not having a basic understanding of client vs server and what each does. From what the OP states in the question, a backend is not needed at all (e.g. an alert-something module has nothing to do with a backend)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly.

All you can do it make a request to the server (XHR), and conditionally execute a function on the client based on the response from the node server. There is no execution path directly between node and the browser.